# What are the donations in Never Let Me Go?

Tags: never-let-me-go

I just read *Never Let Me Go* by Ishiguro Kazuo, and I've been trying to figure out what precisely the four donations are.

I'm guessing it would go a kidney, a lung, perhaps part of the liver, and then something really vital like a heart.  Is it said anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

It's not made clear in the book. There are some brief discussions about which organs might be taken, but the reality is that the students will eventually become *whole body donors* (e.g. with **every single organ** being available to be harvested) after their third or fourth 'donation'.

The implication seems to be that after several donor cycles (presumably liver / pancreas / lung / kidney, etc), the student is probably too weakened to be used for anything other than donating their heart and other internal organs.

> But I’ve gone off a bit. The reason I was talking about all this was
> because the idea of things “unzipping” carried over from Tommy’s elbow
> to become a running joke among us about the donations. The idea was
> that when the time came, **you’d be able just to unzip a bit of
> yourself, a kidney or something would slide out, and you’d hand it
> over. It wasn’t something we found so funny in itself; it was more a
> way of putting each other off our food. You unzipped your liver, say,
> and dumped it on someone’s plate, that sort of thing.** I remember once
> Gary B., who had this unbelievable appetite, coming back with a third
> helping of pudding, and virtually the whole table “unzipping” bits of
> themselves and piling it all over Gary’s bowl, while he went on
> determinedly stuffing himself.

and

> Hannah had the theory that it was their duty to make us have sex because otherwise we wouldn’t be good donors later on. According to her, **things like your kidneys and pancreas didn’t work properly unless you kept having sex.**